# Can't migrate Django app - MySQL throws an OperationalError "Too big scale specified"

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration

I am trying to connect my Django app to a MySQL database. I created the database, and tried migrating the app with `python manage.py migrate`. At this point I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1425, "Too big scale 100 specified for column 'score'. Maximum is 30.")
```

I checked that object in `models.py`. It looks like this:

```
class Para(models.Model):
    ...
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20000)
    score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text[:20]
```

So I changed the `max_digits` to 20, ran `makemigrations` and tried migrating again. But I keep getting the same error. I am new to MySQL, and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing that to

```
score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=5)
```

Followed by another makemigrations will not work (as you have already found out) because the previous migration is what your server is choking on. The simplest solution, delete the two most recent migrations (assuming that you have not made any other changes). Then run

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. It throws another error now- "'Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs'" but the first one is gone!

Comment: with fields like `text = models.CharField(max_length=20000)` it's pretty likely that you will be exhausting the max row size. Please post another question with your full model.